# 0.17.0 way to modify after-decorations?

Tags: monaco-editor

I recently switched from Monaco 0.13.1 to 0.17.0. In my implementation I add some decorations, to show the content of certain variables. As this content can change I loaded custom decorations whenever needed via editor._registerDecorationType and configured it via editor.setDecorations. That way, I could show any text behind the variable as needed. With 0.17.0 both functions were removed and the new way to go seems to be editor.deltaDecorations. Unfortunately, this only allows to define a class and thus only allows to display predefined texts.

I already tried modifying the classes by editing document.styleSheets, which unfortunatly does not seem to neither affect the displayed decoration nor new decorations of that type.

What would be the "new" way to do this? Can I request the editor to reload the documents CSS styles? Or am I going into a completely wrong direction? Is this even still possible in 0.17.0?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around for some time, I realized, that the new way to decorate after a decoration is the CSS ::after flag:

```
.test::after {
  content: 'Test';
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0 0 0 6px;
  color: #353535
}
```

A working example is shown here: https://codepen.io/DrNiels/pen/XWbpgdP

If the decorations should be dynamic, the corresponding CSS style can be adjusted, e.g., by using document.styleSheets